# How to get the event on changing the selected route displaying in a google render container?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the code :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), $scope.map_options);
var dirService= new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var dirRenderer= new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
var dirContainer=document.getElementById('dir-container');


var showDirections = function(dirResult, dirStatus) {
                if (dirStatus != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    alert('Directions failed: ' + dirStatus);
                    return;
              }
              // Show directions
            dirRenderer.setMap(map);
            dirRenderer.setDirections(dirResult);
            dirRenderer.setPanel(dirContainer);
        };

  dirService.route( {origin: '158 cours tolstoi, villeurbanne',
        destination: '8 cours andré philip, villeurbanne',
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
          provideRouteAlternatives: true }
                 , showDirections);
```

I would like to catch the event of selecting another route between the route displaying in the dirContainer.

The alternatives route are displaying in the dirContainer and because provideRouteAlternatives: true.

The event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dirRenderer, 'directions_changed', 
                    function() { 
                alert('a');
            });
```

is not fired when you change the alternative route.

In advance thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the event :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dirRenderer, 'routeindex_changed', 
                    function() { 
                alert(dirRenderer.getRouteIndex());
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

[from this post](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/b368894266f99175/66a23b616186b12f?lnk=gst&q=route+index+changed#66a23b616186b12f) in the v3 API group

There is no event.  There is a feature request to add that to the API:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3565

There *should* be a routeIndex_changed event, but that doesn't seem to work (and isn't documented).  routeindex_changed does work, but I don't see it in the documentation.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directions_changed.html