# Google Maps JavaScript API - Show INACTIVE alternative routes in one color, ACTIVE alternative route in another

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, routes

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API and am providing directions with alternative routes.

I would like to display the INACTIVE alternative routes in a gray color, and the current ACTIVE route in a neon green color.

How can I target the inactive and active route states and control their colors?

I've been able to change the alternative route colors using [Geocodezip's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831558/google-map-alternative-roads-show-with-different-colour) but now I need to target inactive and active states.

[Here's an example of the functionality I'm going for](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Sacramento+Convention+Center,+J+Street,+Sacramento,+CA/Make+Fish+Poke+%26+Sushi+Burrito,+1801+L+St+%2370,+Sacramento,+CA+95814/@38.5769404,-121.4874807,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x809ad0d74b3744fd:0x6a3c5329cc42bc7f!2m2!1d-121.4880673!2d38.5783564!1m5!1m1!1s0x809ad0db9f66fd3d:0xe5143f8b40e02645!2m2!1d-121.4825168!2d38.5751145)

```
for (var j = 0; j < response.routes.length; j++) {
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    polyArray.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: colors[j],
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 5
    }));

    polyArray[polyArray.length - 1].setPath(path);
    for (var i = 0, len = response.routes[j].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
        path.push(response.routes[j].overview_path[i]);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Start: </b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    <b>End: </b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    
        var polyArray = [];
    var colors;

    function initMap() {
        
        polyArray = [];
        colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#ffff00', '#ff00ff', '#00ffff'];
        
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          provideRouteAlternatives: true
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
          for (var j = 0; j < response.routes.length; j++) {
                var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
                polyArray.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                   map: map,
                   strokeColor: colors[j],
                   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                   strokeWeight: 5
                }));
                polyArray[polyArray.length - 1].setPath(path);
                for (var i = 0, len = response.routes[j].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                    path.push(response.routes[j].overview_path[i]);
                }
            }
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @geocodezip Please see the modified fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ucyn9yj9/11/ Can you please assist me with linking the "selected route" to the corresponding route in the directions panel when clicked? I updated the fiddle to include a directions panel. Thank you geocodezip! I can't post as a new question due to down votes :(

Comment: @geocodezip I looked through geocodezip.com and didn't find any examples of this one

Comment: To do what I think you are asking for, you need to add a listener to the DirectionsRenderer on the "routeindex_changed" event.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ucyn9yj9/13/) (the event is not very well documented, the only documented event on the DirectionsRenderer is directions_changed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the event on changing the selected route displaying in a google render container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884292/how-to-get-the-event-on-changing-the-selected-route-displaying-in-a-google-rende)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "activate" a route, process through the array of polylines:

1. set the strokeColor of all the routes to 'grey'
2. set the active route's polyline color to the "active" color

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ucyn9yj9/6/) (based on [my example which you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831558/google-map-alternative-roads-show-with-different-colour), click on the polyline to "activate" it)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var markers = [{
    "title": '',
    "lat": '56.965969',
    "lng": '24.143496',
    "description": ''
  }, {
    "title": '',
    "lat": '56.966259',
    "lng": '24.385860',
    "description": ''
  }];
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var polyArray = [];
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_1"), mapOptions);
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#ffff00', '#ff00ff', '#00ffff'];
  var image = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.966259, 24.385860),
    map: map,
    title: 'Sillava',
    icon: image
  });
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i];
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        provideRouteAlternatives: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          for (var j = 0; j < result.routes.length; j++) {
            var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
            polyArray.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
              map: map,
              strokeColor: "grey",
              strokeOpacity: 0.3,
              strokeWeight: 5
            }));
            if (j == 0) polyArray[0].setOptions({
              strokeColor: '#00ff00',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0
            });
            polyArray[polyArray.length - 1].setPath(path);
            google.maps.event.addListener(polyArray[polyArray.length - 1], 'click', function() {
              for (var i = 0; i < polyArray.length; i++) {
                polyArray[i].setOptions({
                  strokeOpacity: 0.3,
                  strokeColor: "grey"
                });
              }
              this.setOptions({
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeColor: "#00ff00"
              });
            })
            for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[j].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
              path.push(result.routes[j].overview_path[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.975749, 24.279310),
  scrollwheel: false,
  navigationControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  draggable: false,
  styles: [{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#d3d3d3"
    }, {
      "lightness": 17
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#f5f5f5"
    }, {
      "lightness": 20
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }, {
      "lightness": 17
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }, {
      "lightness": 29
    }, {
      "weight": 0.2
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }, {
      "lightness": 18
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }, {
      "lightness": 16
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#f5f5f5"
    }, {
      "lightness": 21
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#dedede"
    }, {
      "lightness": 21
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "on"
    }, {
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }, {
      "lightness": 16
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": 36
    }, {
      "color": "#333333"
    }, {
      "lightness": 40
    }]
  }, {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#f2f2f2"
    }, {
      "lightness": 19
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#fefefe"
    }, {
      "lightness": 20
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#fefefe"
    }, {
      "lightness": 17
    }, {
      "weight": 1.2
    }]
  }]
};
```

```css
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_1" class="map"></div>
```