# Android Google Map Alternate Route and Shortest Path

Tags: android, google-maps

I have searched all over and I haven't found an answer. [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523813/google-maps-javascript-api-show-inactive-alternative-routes-in-one-color-acti)
How can I change the color to the alternate route?  `urlDestination +"&alternatives=true"` 
Adding that code will display the shortest route and alternate routes. Problem is, I don't know how to change the color of the alternate route to a specific color.
Example: Shortest route should be blue and alternate routes should be grey.
Help is much needed.

[Something like this... that the alternate routes should be grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAtV1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/)

You Need to add BelowLine.

```
polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thank  you but that's what my problem is. :( I can only set all of the routes to blue. but I can't change the alternative routes' color. That was my old code even. What I need to do is set the shortest path to blue and the other alternative routes as grey. :(

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward. I believe you have a list or array of Routes.
Iterate through that to find the min distance index. (usually it's the first one, but just to make sure).

```
int minDistanceIndex = 0;
int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++){
    Route route = routes.get(i);
    int distance = route.getDistanceValue();
    if(distance < minDistance){
       minDistance = distance;
       minDistanceIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Now use the minDistanceIndex to show the default route(blue) and others as gray like below.

```
PolylineOptions lineOptions;
for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
    points = routes.get(i).getPoints();
    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
    lineOptions.addAll(points);
    if(minDistanceIndex != i) {
        lineOptions.width(15);
        lineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.darker_gray));
    }
    lineOptions.clickable(true);
    // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
    if(map != null) {
        polylines.add(map.addPolyline(lineOptions));
        map.setOnPolylineClickListener(polylineListener);
    }
}
//finally draw the shortest route
lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
lineOptions.width(18);
lineOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
// Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
if(map != null) {
    polylines.add(map.addPolyline(lineOptions));
}
```

You can add an on click listener to polylines to change the color when user selects another polyline just like in Google Maps.

**IMP: You need to draw the shortest route at last cause otherwise part of that route can be overlapped by alternate route, hence leaving you with part blue and part gray route.**

Hope this helps!